# With BLoC pattern, how to process an event not causing a state change (eg. log), best?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have (simplified) 2 blocs, one global to the app on top of the widget tree (user management) and one for a page within that tree (UI management). Now I want to update data within userBloc from pageBloc based on user input which is not impacting any immediate rendering (directly).

I know the method

```dart
if (userBloc.state is AppSettled)
      myPageUserVar = (userBloc.state as AppSettled).myUserVar;
```

to get the data down and I know how to get the data up by triggering an event. However, I do not know how to process the event without having to release a state change in the upper userBloc. Any ideas someone?

Can I simply add a condition to `mapEventToState` without any yield statement or does this cause any issues (never seen anything like this in the examples)

Comment: Doesn't it violate the rule of Bloc if you DO want to change some data but DON'T want to change the state? What cause you not to change the state? Can you use 2 events like `UserDataUpdatingState` and `UserDataUpdatedState` to fullfill youe goal ?

Comment: Because the state of the screen is controlled with pageBloc. If I send the event "has clicked this button" from pageBloc (where this changes the state) to userBloc as to save it in a central log file, there is no sense to change the userBloc state, since it has no impact on the screen and in general because solely logging data does not change any UI state

Comment: I still think you can add 2 state like `savingCentralLog` and `Done` in userBloc even there is no effect to UI. Otherwise you may not want this be handled in userBloc.

Answer (score 1):

You can either serve a bloc to another bloc via dependency injection like this:

```
class PageBloc extends Bloc {
  final UserBloc userBloc;
  StreamSubscription userBlocSubscription;

  MyBloc(this.userBloc) {
    userBlocSubscription = userBloc.listen((state) {
        // React to state changes here.
        // Add events here to trigger changes in PageBloc.
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    userBlocSubscription .cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

More on that here: [bloc-to-bloc-communication](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)

Another way is to listen to the state change in `pageBloc` and notify your `userBloc` like this:

```
BlocListener<pageBloc, StateA>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    context.bloc<userBloc>().add(...);
  },
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: The upper snippet communicates downwards, right? So in my case from userBloc to pageBloc. I have also implemented DI in this direction. I am not aware how to use the same method in the other direction, so from MyBloc to OtherBloc in the example above. Currently, I have implemented a similar solution to the 2nd snippet, creating an event towards userBloc and there, in the event-state mapping, I store the data without yielding any state change.

Comment: Check the updated answer, to trigger something in userBloc from pageBloc you can try doing it the recommended way, i.e. `userBloc.add(event)` but you could also try just invoking the methods of userBloc too here I guess.